# Is JS 'load' event on script guarantee full script loading?

Tags: javascript, onload, dom-events

I had a trouble with script element async loading guarantees.

When 'load' callback was called on a page with a lot of other scripts, the global variable, which should be defined in external script, was not yet available. On the other hand, after some timeout it became visible. You can see example of how I am doing it:

```js
function async(u, c) {
  var d = document, t = 'script',
      o = d.createElement(t),
      s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
      o.async = true;
  o.src = '//' + u;
  if (c) { var once = false;
                o.addEventListener('load', function (e) { if (!once) { once = true; c(null, e); }}, false);
                o.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    //for IE <= 8
                    if (this.readyState == "complete" || this.readyState == "loaded") {
                        if (!once) { once = true; c(null, e); }
                    }
                }; }
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(o, s);
};

async("cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ifvisible/1.0.6/ifvisible.min.js", function() {
                var f = function() {
                    var activeSent = false;
                    // We detected that sometimes ifvisible is actually undefined !!!
                    if (typeof ifvisible != 'undefined') {
                        ifvisible.on('wakeup', function () {
                            if (!activeSent) {
                                activeSent = true;
                                console.log("I detected this move.")
                            }
                        });
                        ifvisible.idle();
                    } else {
                     console.log("not init.")
                    }
                };
                f();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
<p id="me">
Just move on ME with your mouse
</p>
```

My question - is there a strong or relaxed guarantee that after 'load' callback is invoked, the script was actually fully loaded on the page? Thank you.

Comment: first thing's first, remove the `s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];` line from the script - why is it there in the first place?!

Comment: @BekimBacaj you are right, but this doesn't relate or affect the subject of the question. This code is quick example and about no production usage.